# how to use std::find through ONLY first elements of the vector pair OR a custom vector triplet?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a `vector<triplet>` where triplet is a custom datatype, which is defined as follows:-

```
struct triplet{
   int in, g, o;  //where in denotes index of a triplet element in the vector<triplet>
}
```

So I have a elements in my `vector<triplet>` as follows

```
vector<triplet> v= ({0,4,0},{1,2,0},{2,5,0},{3,4,0});
```

I have a few queries to do on this `vector<triplet>`

1. I want to use `find_if` algorithm to find out if a number `x` is already present in any of `v[i].in` present in the `vector<triplet>`, ie, I want to check if `x` matches to any of `in` of the `triplet` present in the `vector<triplet>` .

I found no examples to do this type of query on the internet. If there is some alternative to use instead of find_if please mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda function.

```
int value_to_find = ...;
find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [=](const triplet& t){ return t.in == value_to_find; });
```

Any time you need a one-off function for some purpose a lambda function is the obvious choice.

Comment: the triplet is captured by reference here(not by value). Should we use ```&``` instead of ```=```?

Comment: The triplet is not captured, is passed to the lambda function as a parameter. It's the `value_to_find` that is captured, and for an integer, capturing by value is fine.

Comment: so can we write ```=value_to_find``` instead of ```=```? Sorry.. i know this question sounds silly...but  still I want to confirm this fact.

Comment: @noobCoder003 Perfectly sensible question. I almost never do it myself but I think the correct syntax to explicitly capture by value is just to use the variable name, no equals sign `[value_to_find](const triplet& t){ return t.in == value_to_find; }`